Jetpack Compose multiline Texts taking up as much space as needed, but equal space when to large
In Jetpack Compose how can I have two Texts next to each other taking up the available width, but if they both don't fit on a single line, the one larger then 50% should become multiline. Then if both are too large they should take up equal amount of space.
This is what I came up with (code is simplified):
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    Text(text = first)
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Text(text = second)
}

With this result:


The 1st and 2nd examples are correct.
The 3rd example is wrong because the second text should be given more space to fit on a single line and the first text should be multiline.
The 4th example is wrong because both should take up 50% of the available space.

